# How to multiple keys in typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I am developing in a React + TypeScript environment.

I want to has multiple keys to the 'content' key.

```
    interface IModalProps {
        isOpen: boolean;
        type: 'basic';
        content: ReactElement;
        options?: IModalOption;
}
```

I imagined it with the code below.

```
interface IModalProps {
        isOpen: boolean;
        type: 'basic';
        [content | children]: ReactElement;
        options?: IModalOption;
}
```

the code above means key would be 'content' or 'children'.

Is there a way to have multiple keys in the type script?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { ReactElement } from 'react'

type IModalOption = {
    tag: 'IModalOption'
}

interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean;
    type: 'basic';
    options?: IModalOption;
}

type Union<T extends string> = T extends string ? Record<T, ReactElement> : never

type IModalProps = Props & Union<'content' | 'children'>

// error, there are no 'content' and/or 'children'
const props: IModalProps = {
    isOpen: true,
    type: 'basic',
    options: {
        tag: 'IModalOption'
    },
}

// ok
const props2: IModalProps = {
    isOpen: true,
    type: 'basic',
    options: {
        tag: 'IModalOption'
    },
    content: null as any as ReactElement
}

// ok
const props3: IModalProps = {
    isOpen: true,
    type: 'basic',
    options: {
        tag: 'IModalOption'
    },
    children: null as any as ReactElement
}

// ok
const props4: IModalProps = {
    isOpen: true,
    type: 'basic',
    options: {
        tag: 'IModalOption'
    },
    children: null as any as ReactElement,
    content: null as any as ReactElement
}
```

`Union` utility type [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) `content | children`.

It means that it is applied to each union. `Union<'content' | 'children'>` returns `Record<'content, ReactElement> | Record<'children, ReactElement>`.

In order to achieve desired behavior, you just need to merge base props with union:

`type IModalProps = Props & Union<'content' | 'children'>`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgJQKYEMDGMCiAbVEVAO3gF84AzKCEOAcig23oFgAoDmATzFTgCSAWQgATdHgDyYGMAjE4AXkQc4auDHQBzAFwNhYidNny27Mhw7BSqKJSz8ACjTABnFe3Vxgr6ST0ARhAQBOjEANyq6jx8evQB6K7AmPSRnuoQMnLErgD8egbiUlnyaRac7DH8AKrE2QA8ACpwqAAeMCSi7q4wUNZaAHxKcM1tHcRdcD19xFpwuSiomNCiTQA0i1i4BESkQ3rEqAButpaVvPyFEs6Z7so3bnAAZHC1DfTLNqT0cAA%20DJgABbAPCiJjEegDM4AemhLSgNCgGxggNs-HQTDgxAgAPk4xgPzComh0ABwNB4LMnx6cDALlcBRERQedw8Xh8fmIel6AFdUGsomoqnEEkkUgL0mpMiYcnoEIKvBptHErsUZWYvGQJeUOLC4BAANYcanwOm3ABMjMMeBZw3lku8vj4XI0UD5Eq8woYouS9A9GRKsrZiqFyv0TKMgY16i1Cs%20%20IOPLweDgiVTxG4qfcaC2%20EIJBgHB17D1huN8hpZrcAGYrcz6XaFRzndy3fyFV74olff6pYGGcGQ5pdOHrcZstG1LGHUCQWD-Fikym02FM2mc9g87tC%20YYXCy%20wTbT6QAWOvXBvKe3sp0L3nth2dn3ihXS7ID68hpUj%20iq8emBVpy8WcKQXYglyzdM12zZhtnzUhezgeMC0TZNINXSCNzg7ciyAA)

Comment: thanks, how can I access property? like const fnA = (e : IModalProps) => { const aa = e.children } ;

Comment: In order to access it, you should  check whether property `children` exists or not with help od conditional statement of custom typeguard. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards . Please see `hasProperty` typeguard in my blog https://catchts.com/FP-style#fp_utils

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
interface IModalPropsBase {
    isOpen: boolean;
    type: 'basic';
    options?: IModalOption;
}

type IModalProps = IModalPropsBase
    & ({ content: ReactElement } | { children: ReactElement });
```

Or mashed into a signle type in case you prefer that:

```
type IModalProps =
  & { isOpen: boolean; type: 'basic'; options?: IModalOption; }
  & ({ content: ReactElement } | { children: ReactElement });
```

To then use it, you can utilize the `in` operator:

```
function Modal(props: IModalProps) {
    const actualContent = 'children' in props ? props.children : props.content;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: how can I access property? like `const fnA = (e : IModalProps) => { const aa = e.children } ;`

Comment: To use it, you need to check if the property exists in the type, do something like `const content = 'children' in props ? props.children : props.content;`